# Graphics asset management software

Tags: version-control

I work in a design studio and need some software to manage graphic resources. We coders are pretty happy with `git` but I need something more user friendly for designers. Preferrably something with Mac OS integration and web interface with server running on Linux or Windows. Price is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Six Revisions posted [a guide to version control for designers](http://sixrevisions.com/project-management/the-ultimate-guide-to-version-control-for-designers/) that has links to some software that integrates with the Adobe suite of design products. [Timeline](http://pixelnovel.com/) looks particularly interesting for its integration with Photoshop, showing thumbnails of various versions and allowing you to grab that version. It backends to Subversion, so you may even be able to make it work with your Git repository with some sort of [SVN-to-Git bridge.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662114/rw-access-git-repository-using-svn-git-svnserver). [GitHub appears to support this](https://github.com/blog/626-announcing-svn-support), but I failed to find any other mature options in my brief search.

Answer (score 0):

Make informed business decisions with the PinkVERIFY ITIL v3 compatible asset management in ServiceDesk Plus, ManageEngine's flagship IT service desk software. Keep track of all your assets-hardware and software-throughout their entire life cycle.

The asset management module in ServiceDesk Plus is packed with thoughtful features, including multiple methods of scanning assets; agent-based scan, barcode scans, network scans, and more help you import all your assets. Ensure compliance using integrated software license management. The asset management module also seamlessly integrates with other ITSM processes, including incident, problem, and change management, to help you track all tickets associated with your assets.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).